# Stop SCOPE_IDENTITY on Entity Framework Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We currently do a number of inserts in our application where we do not care about the ID that is generated from this insert.

After looking at SQL profiler there is always a SCOPE_IDENTITY statement after the insert to get the ID back for the object, under load this is impacting performance and creating database locks that are unnecessary.

Is there any way of asking Entity Framework to add an object without updating the ID?

Comment: Just don't use EF for bulk inserts. The primary delay is that each new row results in an individual INSERT, with the corresponding overhead and locking. It's `INSERT` that takes the locks, not `SCOPE_IDENTITY`. Use [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) to insert multiple rows with minimal blocking and (importantly) [minimal logging](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244(v=sql.105).aspx). The performance difference can be orders of magnitude

Comment: Find it hard to believe SCOPE_IDENTITY() is locking. Its more likely to be a table lock while the insert does its job. How many / what type of indexes do you have on the table? How big is the table? Can you run some profiling on the insert statements?

Comment: How many rows are we talking about?

Comment: Its the lock between the insert and the SCOPE_IDENTITY() call.

Comment: We have seen deadlocks against the primary key for this. The tables arent too large (50,000 rows approx).

Comment: I just happened to stumble upon the locking behavior of `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY` and `INSERT` in a simple test. Begin two transactions in two SSMS tabs with a simple `INSERT` followed by something like `SELECT [IDC] FROM [System_Journal] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [IDC] = scope_identity();` (the query was generated by Entity Framework). The second tab will hang until you call `COMMIT TRANSACTION` in the first tab. The locks are not created if you remove the `SELECT` and leave only `INSERT`.